# Apply Find/Change only within all paragraphs of certain style

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, grep

Would like to know if there is a way to replace "normal returns" with "hard returns" as I would in Find/Change, but only affecting all paragraphs of a certain style (I don't want this change made to text that is of other paragraph styles).

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Find Text icon at the **Find Format** from the Find/Change window and add the paragraph style you need to make the change.

[image: Find/Change]